# codeigniter's controller to main controller in a specific div

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
<li><a href="maine/home#services">SERVICES</a></li>
<li><a href="maine/home#about">ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a href="maine/home#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
```

I'm using CodeIgniter and this code was in a different controller. suppose `http://localhost/defctrl/function1`

I want to return to my homepage `"maine/home"` in a specific div when you click on the list but the above code doesn't work. neither `../maine/home#services.`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try this one. `<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('maine/home'); ?>#services">SERVICES</a></li>`

Comment: I get this error , "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's on the same page you can use

```
<li><a href="#services"
```

if another page

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>{route or controller name}#services"
```

Make sure `URL` helper is loaded and site load with `index.php`

Comment: Thanks for the reply man I appreciate your effort. But still doesn't work.

Comment: Please go over any other of your (recent) answers containing blockquotes. You could be flagged as a repeat offender for using them. I edited this one also.

Comment: You're welcome. I appreciate the positive feedback :-) Some don't take it so well, *cheers*

Comment: ha ha ok ok . Fred-ii ;)